# Does CloseProtocol service necessary after LocateProtocol service?

Tags: uefi, edk2

Hi I'm a beginner in learning UEFI and trying to find out the logic of using protocols.

I've read the source code of `CoreOpenProtocol`, `CoreCloseProtocol` and `CoreLocateProtocol`.

What I've found that while `CoreOpenProtocol` will create a `OPEN_PROTOCOL_DATA` structure and linked into `PROTOCOL_INTERFACE->OpenList`, `CoreLocateProtocol` does not create such structure.

`CoreCloseProtocol` will actually delete the `OPEN_PROTOCOL_DATA` from `PROTOCOL_INTERFACE->OpenList` and free the memory that it took.

So since `CoreLocateProtocol` do not create `OPEN_PROTOCOL_DATA`, the close procedure seems meaningless.

Is that true?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's better to base such a conclusion on the UEFI spec, rather than from reading the code. It is my understanding that it is unnecessary to close handles returned by LocateProtocol, and I don't close them in my code. I thought this understanding was based on a statement in the UEFI spec that it isn't required, but I can't find any such statement. However, the description of CloseProtocol says that it closes a handle "that was previously opened with OpenProtocol", which implies that it shouldn't be used for a handle that was obtained otherwise.

Comment: @prl Thanks a lot. I looked at the spec and found what you've stated. would you like to post this as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again